# Entity Framework - Saving new entity with new child entities

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a Promotion object that has collection of Prizes. Both the promotion and each of the prizes in it's collection are new. The prizes have a PromotionID foreign key which is obviously not set yet as the new Promotion hasn't been saved yet.

Is there any way to save this in one call? When I post to my PromotionController with the promotion object,  Model.isValid fails because the PromotionID of the prizes in the collection hasn't been set yet and so it can't save those.

Can I force it to save the promotion first and then set the promotionID on each of the prizes before saving those? I've tried removing the collection before saving the Promotion and then saving each of those prizes later but model.isValid still fails with the same reason even after I've cleared out the collection on the Promotion object.

[EDIT] I've found the problem. I was actually sending through null as the PromotionID on the prize objects and the error was actually because it couldn't convert null to int32.

Comment: Is ur promotionID property marked with required atribute in that class..?if so then remove it..because entity framework automatically creates a primary key if the name of the property matces is class name and ending wit an ID

Comment: It's not marked with a required attribute but it is not nullable(I'm using database first).

Comment: can u please post the code..